# Gerrit trigger works manually but not automatically

Tags: git, triggers, jenkins, gerrit

I've configured Jenkins to run a job every time my Gerrit project receives a new commit: 
Trigger on Patchset created

I'm using the following versions:

Gerrit trigger 2.11.0

Git Client Plugin 1.6.4

Jenkins ver. 1.512

The problem is I can trigger it manually without problems, but the trigger is not running automatically! I tried to move to version Gerrit trigger 2.9.0 to check if this problem is because the update, but I couldn't manage to go back to that version.

Do you have any idea about why auto trigger doesn't work?
Thanks

Comment: which gerrit version?

Comment: Trigger on: "Patchset Created" but did you input anything in the "Gerrit Project" fields? You should put your project details there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using mixed configuration with Gerrit central and some mirrors that had not the trigger option.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Stuck with the same issue. I am able to build manually from query and build gerrit patches. But, for some reasons jenkins is not starting the build automatically. I have the jenkins user created with streaming events rights, also I verified if jenkins user is able to view event stream by using the following command 

`ssh -p 29418 jenkins@ipaddress gerrit stream-events` 

and view the real time event stream. Can you explain how you worked around this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar issue to sessyargc.jp

Manual search for the change set and trigger of job was working, permissions at Gerrit were set and I could see the streamed message using *ssh -p 29418 @ gerrit stream-events*. But the job wasn't starting automatically upon changeset commit.

The problem was that I needed to go to Jenkins->gerrit-trigger configuration and to press a button in the *Status* column under *Gerrit servers* section. The initial button color was red and after I pressed it, it switched to blue and jobs started triggering.

Comment: Was my issue exactly.. thought it was a status indicator not an on/off button!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Gerrit version >= 2.7, you have most certainly not assigned the [stream events capability](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.8.2/cmd-stream-events.html) to the jenkins user.

Go to `Projects -> List -> All-Projects -> Access` and assign the "Stream Events" Capability (under Administration) to the group containing the user your jenkins uses to access Gerrit (usually "Non-Interactive Users"). If the jenkins user does not yet belong to any group, assign him to the "Non-Interactive Users" group.

In Jenkins -> project configuration, make sure that the Strategy for build is set to **Gerrit Trigger**

Comment: FWIW I just setup Jenkins 2.8.3 yesterday. My gerrit server has been running for several months prior. I followed the setup procedure (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger) to set "Stream Events" but it seems it is already setup by default. The "Label Verified" doesn't exist but still Jenkins and Gerrit is cooperating properly.

Comment: Hi, Yes, for me is the same. I had this configuration on place and still cannot trigger from Git. It was solved after my company fixed the configuration of the mirrors. Some mirrors couldn't send any event and now they can.